# PHP array loop key match

Tags: php, arrays

I just have this image array($images) and I want to loop through this images by given key.

```
$images = array(0=>'image1', 1=>'image2', 2=>'image3');
```

Lets assume that there is this pagination and when I go to each page it should match the image key with page number and return the image. If given image key is not exists it should return the first image. I have the page number in a session and this is what I've managed to do so far.

```
/*Default $key = 1;*/
$key = $_SESSION['page'];
$count = count($images);

$key = $SESSION['key'] = (array_key_exists($key-1, $images)) ? $key : ($_SESSION['key'] > $count? 1 : $_SESSION['key']+1);

$this_image = $images[$key-1];
```

This will loop through images as I go through pages, but I want it to work as shown below.

Page 1 > Key 0, Page 2 > Key 1, Page 3 > Key 2, Page 4 > Key 0, Page 5 > Key 1, Page 6 > Key 2

For an example, If I go to page 5 it should return the image 2 in image array.

I hope this makes sense and would appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Heman

Comment: Use `%` didvide and check the remainder.

Comment: I think this is a little bit confusing as I do not understand how your system works...

Answer (score 3):

```
$total = count($images);
$remainder = $page%$total;
echo $key = ($remainder == 1) ? 0 : (($remainder == 2)  ? 1 : 2);
```

Comment: This will work if array count is equal to 3. Need a bit of modification to work on dynamic array. Good one. Tnx

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
($key > $count) ?  $key = $key%$count : $key = $key-1;
```

Comment: This looks good. Only issue is it would go negative in a scenario where `$key%$count = 0` example: `6%3-1 = -1`

Comment: @Heman you are right, i edited it, and I think this should work, i don't need -1 when is true :d. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your code. One is returning `$key` when `$key - 1` exists while it should be `$key - 1`:

```
$key = (isset($images[$key - 1])) ? $key - 1 : ($key > $count ? $key - $count - 1 : 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

this would work on any scenario.

```
$images = array(0=>'image1', 1=>'image2', 2=>'image3');
$count = count($images);
$remainder = $key%$count;
$remainder = ($remainder == 0) ? $count-1 : ($remainder - 1);
($key > $count) ?  $key = $remainder : $key = $key-1;
```

Special thanks to @M.I and @user1234 and also thanks everyone else for suggestions :)